# How to define the joint probability of continues and discrete variable?

Tags: probability

I came up with the following situation:

I have $X \sim U(0,1)$ and another $Y = I_{(X < p)}$ (where $0<p<1$). Now obviously $Y \sim Bern(p) $.

Is there a way to define the joint probability (or density) of X and Y together ($P_{X,Y}(x,y)$ / $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$)?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but not through some usual PDF, since there is no dentity in this case. You might say that $(X,Y)$ is uniform on the union of two segments $$\left([0,p]\times\{1\}\right)\cup\left([p,1]\times\{0\}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping there is more to it.

Comment: *density, not dentity.